# How do I connect to postgres database that do not use password with pgadmin3..?

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin

I have a **postgres** database that I set up with **SQLAlchemy**, with this code:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "postgresql:///mydb"
```

And now I want to manage my database with **pgAdmin3**, but I'm confused because don't know how to connect it with the username and password form is blank, like this:

[image]

there is the **OK** button was inactive.

before, I know how to connect it if there I set up my username and password in my **SQLAlchemy** configuration:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "postgresql:///myuser:mypassword@localhost/mydb"
```

and if the **SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI** like that, I can connect with **pgAdmin3** like this:
[image]

so, how to connect pgAdmin3 with my **postgres** database if I set up it with no username and password..?

**Note:** this just for my local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no connection without a username.
If `"postgresql:///mydb"` successfully connects to mydb, the username might be taken from your environment variable *$PGUSER*. Otherwise it defaults to your system (OS) username.

You can find your username with `SELECT current_user` (From SQLAlchemy). Then use this to connect with PgAdmin3.

As for the password: Your server might be configured to not require a password. Or you have a password in your *~/.pgpass* file (or the file referenced by *$PGPASSFILE*). These will be used by PgAdmin3 as well.

Comment: Thanks @clamp, Now I can login it on pgAdmin3 with my OS username, and there was no password fill in the form.